# Deploy a rails app using MongoDB, Mongomapper in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

We are planning to deploy a Rails 2.3.8 application which uses MongoDB, on our website. Our present web hosting provider is hostgator and they do not provide support for mongodb.

So, what are the best/cheap hosting companies out there where I can have full stack of Ruby on Rails and MongoDB?

We are looking for cheapest hosting provider since this website will be our first application which we will use on Rails and we are students :)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

What about Amazon EC2? [MongoDB on EC2](http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Amazon%20EC2.html) I have never used EC2, so is installation of Rails 2.3.8 + MongoDB can be a pain there? Approx. how much it Amazon EC2 cost (minimum)?

EC2 at $72 approx (min) is expensive. So default choice is Heroku

Comment: Did you ever get Shapado working on Heroku?

Comment: No. The problem was: Shapado uses Mongomapper and some gem (don't rememeber the name) which for now does not support remote MongoHQ databases (only localhost) and in case of Heroku, mongohq was a remote db. So, it never worked out for me. 

You can go here and look for many answers: http://shapado.com/questions/hosting-companies-where-shapado-has-been-installed-successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://heroku.com/ support the use of MongoMapper against MongoHq. I have only tried the free versions because of small resource requirements, but the prices seem reasonable.

Comment: +1 for heroku; Best part: you can try it out for free until your traffic needs to be dialed up. Free is good! (we've deployed several rails + mongo apps)

Comment: I am trying to deploy shapado on Heroku. Hvaing a hard time. When I do that, will update my post.

Comment: Heroku + MongoHQ is a pain. I am not able to start my app.